# How to return the html of a REMOTE page using only javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am developing an addon for Firefox that will rely on a remote webpage. I need to use pure javascript or one of the supported web APIs to return the complete html of a page. So something like:

```
GET "samplesite.com/page.php" RETURN "contents"
```

XMLHttpRequest actually works exactly the way I need, but it can't be used for remote domains due to security concerns.

Once I get the page, I am going to use javaScript to search it for keywords. That code will look something like:

```
z = remoteDocument.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    var content = z[i].innerHTML;
    var keyword = new RegExp("keyword");
    if (keyword.test(content)) {
        //some code to modify the result
    }
}
```

I do not want to display the returned html, I simply want to be able to search it for keywords.

I found this answer, which I believe does what I want, but it is written in jQuery. I would prefer a solution written in pure JavaScript, but one written in one of the Mozilla web APIs would also work. Note: From what I've found in my research, the Firefox Quantum does not support jQuery or at the very least strongly discourages it.

Comment: Client-side, you're up against CORS. If the source is all you need, you could use AJAX (the XMLHttpRequest) to a PHP page that does the scraping with DOMDocument.

Comment: Use a CORS enabled proxy. Either on a server you control or third party service

Comment: jQuery can't get around CORS.